# wxpython load xrc file then load Frame failed

Tags: python, wxpython, xrc

I use  wxFormBuilder to generate my ui and xrc file 
in python code what i do is:

```
self.res = xrc.XmlResource("abcd_xrc.xrc")
self.frame = self.res.LoadFrame(None, 'MyFrame2')
self.frame.SetSize((750,700))
```

I load the xrc file then load the frame finally I want to chang the frame size 
here the self.frame object is None

the error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ODN-NMM-Python\realease\Test_Cons.py", line 191, in <module>
    app = MyApp(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 8628, in __init__
    self._BootstrapApp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 8196, in _BootstrapApp
    return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ODN-NMM-Python\realease\Test_Cons.py", line 40, in OnInit
    self.Init_frame()
  File "D:\ODN-NMM-Python\realease\Test_Cons.py", line 50, in Init_frame
    self.frame.SetSize((750,700))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetSize'
```

My xrc file's some content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<resource xmlns="http://www.wxwindows.org/wxxrc" version="2.3.0.1">
    <object class="wxFrame" name="MyFrame2">
        <style>wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL</style>
        <size>500,300</size>
        <title></title>
        <centered>1</centered>
        <aui_managed>0</aui_managed>
        <object class="wxBoxSizer">
            <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
            <object class="sizeritem">
                <option>1</option>
                <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                <border>5</border>
                <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                    <orient>wxHORIZONTAL</orient>
                    <object class="sizeritem">
                        <option>2</option>
                        <flag>wxEXPAND | wxALL</flag>
                        <border>5</border>
```

the name of my xrc frame is exactly "MyFrame2" but when I load it, obviously the return object is wrong, so the error occurred.

Comment: Are you sure that you are loading the correct xrc file? `LoadFrame` returns `None` when it can't find the requested frame and then you get the `AttributeError`.

Comment: yes, I use wxFormBuilder to generate my xrc file sometimes it works sometimes not. I really do not know the reasono

Comment: I know this error, because I used chinese in some wxpython title, so the xrc file can not be right read. Thanks